# GitHub pull requests vs. Git command line merging

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

When working with and closing a pull request you have three merge options  **Create a merge commit**, **Squash and merge** and **Rebase and merge**. I wonder how these options translate into actual Git commands - especially with regards to `--no-ff`.

The merge dialog lists these two (step 1 & step 2) examples:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
git merge master
```

And:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff develop
git push origin master
```

But I'm confused as these are the same examples for all three options. This can't be right. So I guess I just misunderstood the user interface here.

What are the commands for Git and is `--no-ff` being used anywhere?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> When working with and closing a pull request you have three merge options **Create a merge commit**, **Squash and merge** and **Rebase and merge**. I wonder how these options translate into actual Git commands - especially with regards to `--no-ff`.

- The GitHub "make a merge" button corresponds to:

  ```
  git checkout <branch>
  git merge --no-ff -m <message> <commit-hash>
  ```

  where the *`message`* part is something you'd have to generate by hand, since your local Git does not know the details of the pull request (its number, and any other repository).  The *`branch`* part is your target branch: the one you want the merge commit to be on, after the merge completes.

  Note that you must have the specified *`commit-hash`* commit object in your repository at this point.  GitHub's behind-the-scenes manipulation means that it *is* available in the Git repository on GitHub, but it's listed under a `refs/pull/` reference, rather than a branch name, in that repository.
- The GitHub "squash and merge" button corresponds to:

  ```
  git checkout <branch>
  git merge --squash <commit-hash>
  git commit
  ```

  with the `git commit` being required because the command-line `--squash` flag turns on the command-line `--no-commit` flag.
- The GitHub "rebase and merge" button corresponds—somewhat roughly—to:

  ```
  # maybe: create a branch name (consider using git checkout -b next)
  git checkout <commit-hash-or-branch-name>
  git rebase <branch>
  git checkout <branch>
  git merge --ff-only <hash-or-name>
  # maybe: delete a branch name
  ```

  This is the most complicated one: the *`commit-hash-or-name`* is either the commit hash ID that you would supply to the other two, or a branch name that identifies that commit hash ID, preferably a temporary name you just made up for the duration of this operation.  The `git rebase` operation must then succeed on its own—if not, GitHub itself won't offer you the ability to do a rebase-and-merge.

  If the rebase operation *does* succeed *and* you chose to do it with a detached HEAD, you must now save the hash ID of the rebased commit.  If you chose to do it using some temporary branch name, nothing special is required at this point.

  Now that the original chain of commits has been copied by the rebase operation, *now* you `git checkout` the branch you want to update-by-fast-forward and run the `git merge --ff-only` operation.  The name or hash ID you supply here is the one that the successful rebase operation either produced as the tip of the detached HEAD, or updated into the temporary branch name.

  If you used a temporary branch name, you should now delete that temporary branch name.